# How to load JS into chrome from computer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Im trying to load this javascript (with bookmark) in Google Chrome for plug.dj.
The Google Chrome says in console this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U81hH.jpg
I donk know why.

Im using this tutorial https://github.com/backus/Plug.DJ-Javascript-Chatbot#how-to-compile-and-run

This is the javascript code:

```
javascript:$.getScript('[YOUR INCLUDE LOCATION]');
```

I replaced location

```
javascript:$.getScript('[E:\plugbot\bin\bot.js]'); <- not working
javascript:$.getScript('[file:///E:\plugbot\bin\bot.js]'); <- not working
javascript:$.getScript('E:\plugbot\bin\bot.js'); <- not working
javascript:$.getScript('file:///E:\plugbot\bin\bot.js'); <- not working
```

The file E:\plugbot\bin\bot.js exists.

Comment: Make a domain-relative reference to the file.  If your webpage is running on `/path/to/page` then do `$.getScript('/path/to/page/plugblot/bin/bot.js')`.  This also depends on where the document root is (assumed in this case to be `/`, but the script source doesn't need to know about it).

Comment: Hello, thanks for comment. The script is on my computer in drive "E". Webpage `plug.dj` is not my server.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be adding script to a web page which loads data from your disk. This is not permitted, for good reason: if it were, then web sites could steal information from your computer.

Instead, you must put your script on a web server — the domain doesn't matter for scripts — so that you can write a `http://...` URL instead of a `file:...` one where you have it now.

Another option is to put the script you want to add (`bot.js`) into a browser extension which can insert it directly into the page. There's probably a generic extension that can do that for you without any additional programming, even, but I'm not familiar with the field.

Comment: Yes. But I can't fint normal webhosting with node.js :( . Thanks.

Comment: @DavidLences You don't need node.js. You just need to serve your js file.